# eError, ProgrammingError, OperationalError in Heroku tutorial for Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, heroku

I'm trying to do the Heroku tutorial for Python and I keep getting an error when I try to start the app locally (the command `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows`).

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web.1  | eError, ProgrammingError, OperationalError
web.1  | getting-started\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
web.1  | env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, in <module>
web.1  | \main_folder\python-getting-started\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 129, in load_backend
```

I have no idea what's going on, can anybody help? I had trouble install ingpsycog2 at first and then used the easy_install method, I'm not sure if that will affect it.

I'm using Python 3.4, the latest version of PostGreSQL and I'm on Windows